# Leaflet _ NextJS - my app displays marker and popup weirdly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, next.js

***edit: I have found that to stick the marker on position I have to use the same value for iconSize and iconAnchor. But still seek how to align the popUp on the icon.***

***edit2: edit2 is more an hint, I think in fact my component is well rendered but for some reason when the page calculates the position of the popup there  is some lag that put it on a wrong position. For proof, if I click on the icon to re-render the popUp it appear at well, rawly a relevant position to just slightly adjustate. So, the solution could be to find a mean to reajust the popUp display.*** I confirm this hint, using a setTimeout to set the popUp cure the problem even if it is on the hackway it's works on the principle.

I'm trying to build a leaflet map with NextJS. 
Currently my app displays the marker and popup outside the location determine in lng and lat. 
I'm a few confused since to start only the CDN works, not the local files. But then, when I place the cosmetics on my app, the system just breaks and my popup go near to the ocean, the marker leave for an other city, so what's going on? I can't figure out what is going on.

*One interesting element is that my icon go near the location when I zoom. When I zoomdown, seems the icon go farther from the location, it's like the element doesn't stick to the location.*

Here my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yv585k880j.

Here a photo of the situation:

[image]

Here my react.js code:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from "react"; 
import L from "leaflet" 
import   "~/lib/leaflet/leaflet.css"
import "~/lib/leaflet/leaflet"
import styled from "styled-components"
import Head from 'next/head' 

const Wrapper= styled.div`
  width:${props => props.width};
  height:${props => props.height};
`;

export default class Map extends Component{ 
  componentDidMount(){  
    this.map= L.map("map", { 
      center:[37.8349,-122.1297],
      zoom:12,
      zoomControl:true
    })
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19,
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    })
    .addTo(this.map)
    var placeholder = L.icon({
      iconUrl: "/static/assets/icons/placeholder.svg",       
      iconSize:     [37, 37],           
      iconAnchor:   [37.8349, -122.1297], // [37,37] to stick icon to location
     relative to the iconAnchor
  });

    var marker = L.marker([37.8349, -122.1297],{icon: placeholder}).addTo(this.map);
    marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.").openPopup();
  }

  render(){
    // console.log("this.map.invalidateSize: ", this.map) 
    return (
      <Fragment>
          <Head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
   crossorigin=""/> 

     <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
   crossorigin=""></script> 


          </Head>
        <Wrapper width="100vw" height="80vh" id="map"/>
        {/* <style jsx global>{lStyle}</style> */}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: I have found that to stick the marker on position I have to use the same value for iconSize and iconAnchor. But still seek how to align the popUp on the icon

Comment: edit2: edit2 is more an hint, I think in fact my component is well rendered but for some reason when the page calculates the position of the popup there  is some lag that put it on a wrong position. The solution could be to find a mean to reajust the popUp display.

Comment: I confirm the hint of edit2, using a setTimeout cure the problem even if it is on the hackway it's works on the principle.